# Library Function to have Unique Items (remove duplicated) Array is not running

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a "Library Function" to remove duplicated array entries. I have written following snippet but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help fix it?

```js
var arr1 = [5, 4, 2, 6, 9, 2, 8, 1, 6];

Array.prototype.unique = function(arr){
  var result = [];
    arr.forEach(item){
      if(result.indexOf(item) === -1){
        result.push(item);
      }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(arr1.unique());
```

Comment: please define "doesn't seem to work." what error messages did you get in your console?

Comment: @DanO - You can run here only - by clicking the blue button.

Comment: it is not "nearly impossible" to ask Stack Overflow questions; your account has asked 294 of them as of this comment. it is also perfectly acceptable to downvote a question if it shows no research effort, which this does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you.

No need to pass an argument, you can access array using `this`

```js
var arr1 = [5, 4, 2, 6, 9, 2, 8, 1, 6];
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
  var result = [];
  this.forEach((item) => {
    if (result.indexOf(item) === -1) {
      result.push(item);
    }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(arr1.unique());
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are attempting to do is the following. The small change I made was to use the this keyword to reference the array itself. Also the function needs to be inside the foreach(fn => {}).

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
   var result = [];
   this.forEach(function(item) {
     if(result.indexOf(item) === -1) {
      result.push(item);
     }
   })
 return result;
}
```

Making a version that uses an arrow function inside the foreach loop and uses includes, so you have some options.

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
  var result = [];
  this.forEach(item => {
    if (!result.includes(item)) {
      result.push(item);
    }
  })
 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In console.log() must be :

```
console.log(arr1.unique(arr1));
```

your unique function receives an array as a parameter

Comment: yes, but it's not that it doesn't work, you're declaring it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this, You can try this

```js
let arr1 = [5, 4, 2, 6, 9, 2, 8, 1, 6];

let result= Array.from(new Set(arr1))
console.log(result)
```